# I'm using Dask to apply LabelingFunction using Snorkel on multiple datasets but it seems to take forever. Is this normal?

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe, snorkel

My problem is as follow:
I have several datasets (900K, 1M7 and 1M7 entries) in csv format which I load into multiple Dask Dataframe.
Then I concatenate them all in one Dask Dataframe that I can feed to my Snorkel Applier, which applies a bunch of Labeling Function to each row of my Dataframe and return a numpy array with as many rows as there are in the Dataframe and as many columns as there are Labeling Functions.

The call to Snorkel Applier seems to take forever when I do that with 3 datasets (more than 2 days...). However if I just run the code with only the first dataset, the call takes around 2 hours. Of course I don't do the concatenation step.

So I was wondering how can this be ? Should I change the number of partitions in the concatenated Dataframe ? Or maybe I'm using Dask badly in the first place ?

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
from snorkel.labeling.apply.dask import DaskLFApplier
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import os

start = time.time()

applier = DaskLFApplier(lfs)  # lfs are the function that are going to be applied, one of them featurize one of the column of my Dataframe and apply a sklearn classifier (I put n_jobs to None when loading the model)

# If I have only one CSV to read
if isinstance(PATH_TO_CSV, str):
    training_data = dd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV, lineterminator=os.linesep, na_filter=False, dtype={'size': 'int32'})
    slices = None
 
# If I have several CSV  
elif isinstance(PATH_TO_CSV, list):
    training_data_list = [dd.read_csv(path, lineterminator=os.linesep, na_filter=False, dtype={'size': 'int32'}) for path in PATH_TO_CSV]
    training_data = dd.concat(training_data_list, axis=0)

    # some useful things I do to know where to slice my final result and be sure I can assign each part to each dataset
    df_sizes = [len(df) for df in training_data_list]
    cut_idx = np.insert(np.cumsum(df_sizes), 0, 0)
    slices = list(zip(cut_idx[:-1], cut_idx[1:]))

# The call that lasts forever: I tested all the code above without that line on my 3 datasets and it runs perfectly fine
L_train = applier.apply(training_data)

end = time.time()
print('Time elapsed: {}'.format(timedelta(seconds=end-start)))
```

If you need more info I will try to get them to you as much as I can.
Thank in you advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by default `applier` function is using processes, so does not benefit from additional workers you might have available:

```py
# add this to the beginning of your code
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
# you can see the address of the client by typing `client` and opening the dashboard

# skipping your other code

# you need to pass the client explicitly to the applier
# after launching this open the dashboard and watch the workers work :)
L_train = applier.apply(training_data, scheduler=client)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I'm trying this solution. Looks like workers exceed memory so I'm trying to specify manually the number of workers and threads.

I am not sure if this will solve my current problem. I'll let you know if there is still a problem.

Comment: Sure, if memory is the problem I would try first try it on a small sample (e.g. if you feed it a very small `csv` file, does it work?) and if that works, then repartition the csv into more partitions to reduce the memory load per worker.

Comment: Ok. So I ran my code with what you suggested me to add without changing anything on a sample of 10K entries. That should represent a few Mb I think: memory_usage(deep=True) gives 21Mb.
I get the following error: 
"distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker"

Oh ! Also, I tried to repartition the dask Dataframe since by default it has only one partition (since the data is not big enough I guess). I tried with 10 partitions. But I have the error too.

Comment: Actually I don't have an error if I don't change the number of partitions, which might be logic though since there is only one.
But I still got the error with 10 partitions :/

Comment: There is an issue without a solution here: https://github.com/snorkel-team/snorkel/issues/1586. If I understand `snorkel` correctly, those `lfs` functions are parallelisable (they don't share any state across partitions), if so how about solving this with `delayed`? Would that be a problem?

Comment: Actually some of those `lfs` use some information processed before on the dataset and store in a `dict` as an attribute of an object. So it might be the source of my memory problem. I guess the object pass to those `lfs` is copied for each partition though it should not be that big :/

Comment: I forgot ! One of my `lfs` use a `sklearn model`. I checked the size of the serialized model and it is 265Mb. Is there an easy to way to make that kind of read-only data "shareable" ? So it does not consume so much memory ?

Comment: In general you would use `fut_value = client.scatter(some_big_object, broadcast=True)` and then pass the `fut_value` into relevant functions (that used `some_big_object`), but it's hard to say whether that would resolve this issue...

Comment: I eventually repartitionned my big dataframe with more partitions (multiplying it by some number) without using the client solution.
I don't think it's the optimal solution but it reduces the computation time so that's fine.

I tried using `scatter` or even some sklearn wrapper from dask to speed-up the prediction step but the prediction is used in my LF (applied on one item rather than my whole dataset) so it does not change much.
Some of my code should be changed to optimize the all thing correctly I guess. For now I'm going to stay with the repartition solution.

Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome, I wish I could help more, but this is a tricky situation.